# avcodec_open segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, libavcodec

Good afternoon,

I got a copy of the ffmpeg's api-example.c (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/api-example_8c-source.html). I tested the function video_encode_example() and got the code working as expected.

I then re-factored this function into different class methods and now I get a seg fault with the call to avcodev_open(). I then changed the code to call the original video_encode_example() from a class method and the calls to avcodec... were successful.

It appears that when called from a function (eg video_encode_example()), the behaviour is as expected, but avcodev_open fails when called from a class method. I traced the code and in both cases the values for the avcodev_open() arguments are assigned (and similar) pointer values. cgdb reports that the seg fault occurs in avcodev_open2()

Any suggestions? 
The code was compiled and tested on a Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit machine) using the libav package available thru apt-get (libavcodec.so.53.35.0)

Regards,
Daniel

Added comment following the first response:

From the link above, I copied the function video_encode_example() and placed the call inside a class constructor. This part is working.

```
VideoEncoder::VideoEncoder( const std::string& aFileName)
    : mCodec( NULL)
    , mCodecContext( NULL)
    , picture (NULL)
    , mFileName( aFileName)
    , mFileHandler( NULL)
{
    // must be called before using avcodec lib
    ::avcodec_init();

    // register all the codecs
    ::avcodec_register_all();

    video_encode_example( aFileName.c_str());
    return;
    ...
}
```

The re-factored part includes splitting the avcodev call (from the original video_encode_example() function) to different VideoEncoder methods. The constructor now looks like:

```
VideoEncoder::VideoEncoder( const std::string& aFileName)
    : mCodec( NULL)
    , mCodecContext( NULL)
    , picture (NULL)
    , mFileName( aFileName)
    , mFileHandler( NULL)
{
    // must be called before using avcodec lib
    ::avcodec_init();

    // register all the codecs
    ::avcodec_register_all();

    // find the mpeg1 video encoder
    mCodec = ::avcodec_find_encoder( CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    if (!mCodec) {
        fprintf( stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit( 1);
    }

    mCodecContext = ::avcodec_alloc_context3( mCodec);
    picture = ::avcodec_alloc_frame();

    // put sample parameters
    mCodecContext->bit_rate = 400000;

    // frames per second
    mCodecContext->time_base = (AVRational){1,25};
    mCodecContext->gop_size = 10;               // emit one intra frame every ten frames
    mCodecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    mCodecContext->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    // open it
    // Initializes the AVCodecContext to use the given AVCodec. Prior to using this function the context has to be allocated.
    if (::avcodec_open( mCodecContext, mCodec) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit( 1);
    }

    mFileHandler = fopen( mFileName.c_str(), "wb");
    if (!mFileHandler) {
        fprintf( stderr, "could not open %s\n", mFileName.c_str());
        exit( 1);
    }

}
```

The call to avcodec_open causes the seg fault. In addition, the fault occurs whether using avcodev_.. or ::avcodev_...

Comment: You'll have to share more.  You say that code was working, you made secret changes, now it's broken?  I suggest that you roll back your changes until it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not set the `.width`/`.height` members of `mCodecContext`, and this causes the crash later on.

Ubuntu 12.04 ships with the `ffmpeg` fork `libav` in version 0.8 which is more compatible with `ffmpeg` 1.0+ or even later `ffmpeg` versions IIRC. I assume you're using that repository version and have used `libav-0.8.12` during testing myself (although personally I very much prefer the *real* `ffmpeg`, which is `ffmpeg-2.2` at the moment).

Interestingly, using `ffmpeg-2.2` (using `av_codec_open2`) instead of `libav-0.8` does not crash, but instead just normally returns failure and prints a warning about width and height being unset (another pro-point for `ffmpeg` instead of `libav`).

Comment: You nailed it, thanks. I was setting the width/height after the call to avcodec_open, in another method. I am indeed using libav-0.8,meets my needs for the moment.

Comment: Since I "nailed" it, consider marking my answer as accepted (checkmark on the left) and/or upvoting it.